# Is there any way to have multiple Vues have a computed listener working on the same value?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, computed-observable

**Setup:**

I have multiple Vue components, and each component has multiple instances in different dialogs in my web app.

For each type of component I have a global state (`handrailOptions` in the example below) so that each type of component stays in sync across the dialogs.

I'd like for it so that when a component proceeds beyond step 1, I hide the other components in that dialog.

I have achieved this nicely using the computed / watch combo.

However, my problem is that it seems if I try to listen in with computed through more than 1 Vue instance, it hijacks the other listeners.

**Problem**

Below is a simplified version of what I'm working with, when the app starts up, the console logs 'computed 1' & 'computed 2'. But then when I change `handrailOptions.step`, only the second fires. ('computed 2' & 'watched 2')

Is there any way to have multiple Vues have a computed listener working on the same value?

```
handrailOptions = {
    step: 1
};

Vue.component( 'handrail-options', {
    template: '#module-handrail-options',
    data: function() {
        return handrailOptions;
    },
});

var checkoutDialog = new Vue({
    el: '#dialog-checkout',
    computed: {
        newHandrailStep() {
            console.log('computed 1');
            return handrailOptions.step;
        }
    },
    watch: {
        newHandrailStep( test ) {
            console.log('watched 1');
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#dialog-estimate-questions',
    computed: {
        newHandrailStep() {
            console.log('computed 2');
            return handrailOptions.step;
        }
    },
    watch: {
        newHandrailStep( test ) {
            console.log('watched 2');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what is `handrailOptions`? What is `newHandrailStep`?

Comment: Assumed that `handrailOptions` is a global variable and that is its bound in data with `data.handrailOptions.step` instead of `data.handrailOptions` i understand your problem. Because vue cannot bind to the object reference, it binds to the value and is therefore unable to update other instances. Try to bind the object, not the object-properties in the data section => `data:{ handrailOptions: handrailOptions}`

Comment: @RoyJ `handrailOptions` is the global state I mentioned, I edited my answer to add it in the code. `newHandrailStep` is the variable computed makes for `handrailOptions.step` so that I can watch it in the vue instance.

Comment: @Reiner I think there might be a misunderstanding? I bind the whole object to data for the component. But I want each Vue instance to watch for the property `step` changing.

This works fine for 1 Vue, but whenever I add another Vue, only the newest Vue fires the watch function when `handrailOptions.step` changes.

(I tried watching the entire `handrailOptions` object but that didn't work)

Comment: Do you make an instance of the `handrail-options` component? Vue isn't going to make `handrailOptions` responsive until you do. (I presume that's the reason you have set it up that way.)  I would probably just do `new Vue({data: handrailOptions})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as expected. I made `handrailOptions` responsive by making the data object of a new `Vue`. Making it the data object of a component, as you did, could also work, but the component would have to be instantiated at least once. It makes more sense to have a single object for your global, anyway.

```js
handrailOptions = {
  step: 1
};

// Make it responsive
new Vue({data: handrailOptions});

var checkoutDialog = new Vue({
  el: '#dialog-checkout',
  computed: {
    newHandrailStep() {
      console.log('computed 1', handrailOptions.step);
      return handrailOptions.step;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    newHandrailStep(test) {
      console.log('watched 1');
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#dialog-estimate-questions',
  computed: {
    newHandrailStep() {
      console.log('computed 2', handrailOptions.step);
      return handrailOptions.step;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    newHandrailStep(test) {
      console.log('watched 2');
    }
  }
});

setInterval(() => ++handrailOptions.step, 1500);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog-estimate-questions">
  Main step {{newHandrailStep}}
</div>
<div id="dialog-checkout">
    CD step {{newHandrailStep}}
</div>
```